# Tasting my uncarbonated beer: Bitter.

Tags: troubleshooting, bitterness

OK, so I'm now bottling my first batch. I opened the primary fermenter (did not use a secondary) and I've racked the beer to the bottling container. It smells hoppy and delicious. I'm pleased.

I taste just a bit before I begin to bottle... and it tastes... bitter. Sort of burned maybe.

I know (now) I didn't do a good enough job pouring the wort off the trub - I definitely left too much trub in the fermenter. Is that the reason? Will it mellow as it bottle conditions? Should I trash the whole batch?

I'm bummed and looking for some direction - I appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/why-do-all-my-beers-taste-better-after-having-aged-for-a-couple-months/3118#3118) answers your question.  Your beer is young and very green.  It needs time to age.  Don't despair. Give it time, both to carbonate in the bottle and age a bit after that.

Many home brewers are too quick to judge in the primary, secondary, or bottle bucket.  Excellent beer takes time.  I've had beers that are TERRIBLE in the bottle bucket and AWESOME after a few months to age.

Your beer will be fine!  Be patient.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I'm already mid-boil on a Brown Ale to back this one (my first real batch (non-Mr. Beer)) up.

Answer (score 1):

A lot happens during carbonation. I just finished an ESB batch that was intensely bitter before carbonation, but tastes quite fine now. Bottle it up and see what happens.

Comment: Tis bottled now. My buddy thought it wasn't as bad as I did. We'll see in two to three weeks.

Comment: After 4 weeks, this turned into a really tasty little beer. It took a good long while for the bitter/metallic taste to finish out, but it did (just as I finished it) get quite tasty.